# UsernameToken in .NET Core. Remove alias xml

Tags: xml, .net-core, wsdl

I must migration old project from .net framework 4.8 to .net core 5.0 and I have problem with connecting wsdl services in project .net standard 2.0.

I was create imitation class of SecurityWS:

```
public class SecurityWS : MessageHeader
{
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _nonce;
    private readonly string _created;
    private readonly string _password;

    public override string Name { get; } = "Security";

    public override string Namespace { get; } =
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";


    private string GenerateNonce()
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[16];
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(nonceBytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
    }

    private string GenerateUTCDate()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    }

    public SecurityWS(string username, string password)
    {
        _username = username;
        _nonce = GenerateNonce();
        _created = GenerateUTCDate();
        _password = password;
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UsernameToken));

        var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        namespaces.Add("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        PasswordWSSecurity passwordWs = new PasswordWSSecurity
        {
            Type =
                    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"
            //Type #PasswrodDigest mean PasswordOption.SendHashed in Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens
        };
        passwordWs.Value = passwordWs.GetValuePasswordDigestStandard(_password, _nonce, _created);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter,
            new UsernameToken
            {
                Id = $"SecurityToken-{Guid.NewGuid()}",
                Username = _username,
                Password = passwordWs,
                Nonce = _nonce,
                Created = _created
            },
            namespaces);
        }

        string xml = sb.ToString();
        int index = xml.IndexOf("?>");
        string xmlWithoutDeclaration;
        if (index != -1)
        {
            xmlWithoutDeclaration = xml.Substring(index + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            xmlWithoutDeclaration = xml;
        }
        writer.WriteRaw(xmlWithoutDeclaration);
    }
```

and when I want create header like this:

```
if (IsCoreProject)
            {
                header = new Varyon.Engine.Services.WSSecurity.SecurityWS(user, password);
            }
            else
            {
                UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(user, password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);
                header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
                    "Security",
                    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                    token.GetXml(new XmlDocument())
                );
            }



            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(service.InnerChannel))
            {
                if (header != null)
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
                return response = service.getUFGPartyHistory(requestHeader, ufgPartyHistory);

            }
```

I get error 'Failed to assert identity with UsernameToken' . I think reason is because in header i got 'xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"'. How can I remove this 'xml alias'?

UsernameToken:

```
[XmlRoot("UsernameToken", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class UsernameToken
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")] 
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public PasswordWSSecurity Password { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Nonce { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Created { get; set; }
}
```

I was based on this site:  https://stapp.space/using-soap-security-in-dotnet-core/
and as like you see he have correct result security header.

Comment: Usually you get an error when reading UTF-16 when you deserialize.  I do not see any reading (deserialize) in the code above.  You do not need the first line with the UTF-16 so I normally just use a streamreader to open the file and then use readline to skip the first line.

Comment: Not really. Function MessageHeader.CreateHeader create a line <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?> and it's too late for change this.

Comment: Replace the code ".GetXml(new XmlDocument())"   It is the new XmlDocument() that is the issue.  I sometime use the Parse method to get the document where I can use a string for the method : XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root></root>");